# Using the Bitcoin API, how can I see the sending address?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, api

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list

I have a transaction and I want to see what addresses the inputs came from. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `gettransaction` on the transaction ID, the keys used to claim the inputs are in the `scriptSig` fields. They're the string starting with `04`. You'll have to hash them and then convert them to base58 get account IDs.

Note that these account IDs may or may not actually mean anything. If you're being paid out of "change", then the account IDs are essentially random.

Comment: David, I don't see a scriptSig field. Perhaps you're thinking of `getrawtransaction`?